# line breaks in dialog service content ignored

Tags: kendo-ui-angular2

Inserting line breaks in content of kendo dialog service window. Kendo Angular 6  dialog in @rogress. line break characters are ignored.

tried html element br and \n, \n. e.g. It displays the character text "\n\n\n" in one continuous line

```
const dialog: DialogRef = this.dialogService.open({
  title: alertTitle,
  content: "Want multiple line breaks here-> \n\n\n so this appears 3 lines below on another line",
  actions: a,
  width: 400,
  height: 205,
  minWidth: 250
});
```

Comment: Fix was to override the Kendo styles for the class   .k-dialog-content {
  // allow new lines and spaces in dialog popup
    white-space: pre-wrap;
    }

Comment: You can create an answer out of your comment and mark it as accepted to close the question.

Answer (score 5):

Fix was to override the Kendo styles for the class .k-dialog-content { // allow new lines and spaces in dialog popup white-space: pre-wrap; }