# get [Object object ] when using panelbar Angular

Tags: angular, kendo-ui

I am trying to bind local data to kendo panelbar but I get [object object] instead of correct data.

In my component :

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PanelBarItemModel } from '@progress/kendo-angular-layout';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  styles: [`
    :host /deep/ .k-content {
        padding: 4px 8px;
     }
`  ],
  template: `
    <div class="panelbar-wrapper">
       <kendo-panelbar [items]="ad"></kendo-panelbar>
   </div>`
  })

  export class AppComponent {
    x : any = [{'adress' : '124 JD'}, {'housenum': 1254}]
    public ad: Array<PanelBarItemModel> = [
      <PanelBarItemModel> {title: 'Address info', content: this.x },
   ];
 }
```

This is what I have when I run it :
[image]

Can anyone help me please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<PanelBarItemModel> {title: 'Address info', content: this.x },` content value should be string and not array of objects
You can write like

```
public ad: Array<PanelBarItemModel> = [
      <PanelBarItemModel> {title: 'Address info', content: `Address- ${this.x[0].adress}, housenum - ${this.x[1].housenum}` },
   ];
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! Can you please help me to do a line break after the word Address ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54737319/line-breaks-in-dialog-service-content-ignored You will need similar like this